# How to connect Database in Laravel with Docker

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem when I use Terminal to migrate or make some command, I am getting error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for database failed: Name or service not known
```

My ENV:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=database
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=products
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

These informations are in the Docker too. And code works on localhost when I open app, but in terminal I am getting error. When I change DB_HOST to localhost or 127.0.0.1 then it works in terminal, but it doesn't work on app on web and it doesn't save data in same database. I don't know what else to do. Is there any way to make to work both and terminal and the web.

```
database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: database
    ports:
      - ${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: products
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      - .docker/database/entrypoint/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - app-network
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by executing commands (php artisan...) in terminal of `Docker` or executing it calling firstly `docker exec -it php-fpm /bin/bash` `(php-fpm is my container name)